# Google Pay for Passes: How to show a message on lock screen for Loyalty

Tags: php, lockscreen, google-pay

I use the repo https://github.com/google-pay/passes-rest-samples for generating google loyalty passes. This works perfectly.

Since there are only methods to create here, I would like to add "patch" to this class collection, for example to update the balance and show the new balance to the card holder.

The update seems to work, because when I open the pass in the gPay app I can see the changed score.

My question is: Is it possible to display a message on the lock screen of a smartphone so that the card holder can see that the score has changed. How can this be done?

***In the comments @Soc pointed out, that it might only be available for flight passes. Can someone confirm/disconfirm this assumption?***

**New Code in Services.php**

```
public function updateSkinnyJwt($objectId) {

    // get instance
    $restMethods = RestMethods::getInstance();

    // read objectId
    $readObject = $restMethods->getLoyaltyObject($objectId);

    // change balance
    $balance = new Google_Service_Walletobjects_LoyaltyPointsBalance();
    $balance->setString("1.145.530");
    $loyaltyPoints = new Google_Service_Walletobjects_LoyaltyPoints();
    $loyaltyPoints->setBalance($balance);
    $loyaltyPoints->setLabel("Points");
    $readObject->setLoyaltyPoints($loyaltyPoints);

    $messages = $readObject->getMessages();

    // Define new message
    $newMessage = array(
        'header' => 'Important Notice',
        'body' => 'Your points has been updated!',
        'kind' => 'walletobjects#walletObjectMessage'
    );

    // Add the new message about updates to the Offer Object
    array_push($messages, $newMessage);
    $readObject->setMessages($messages);

    // update objectId
    $ret = $restMethods->updateLoyaltyObject($objectId, $readObject);
    print_r($ret); // just for debug 

    echo "update done\n";
}
```

**New Code in RestMethods.php**

```
public function updateLoyaltyObject($objectId, $loyaltyObject){
    $response = NULL;

    // Use the Google Pay API for Passes Java client lib to insert an Loyalty object
    //// check the devsite for newest client lib: https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/support/libraries#libraries
    //// check reference API to see the underlying REST call:
    //// https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/reference/v1/loyaltyobject/insert
    //// The methods to call these from client library are in Walletobjects.php
    $service = new Google_Service_Walletobjects($this->client);

    try {
        $response = $service->loyaltyobject->patch($objectId, $loyaltyObject);
        $response["code"] = 200;
    } catch (Google_Service_Exception $gException)  {
        $response = $gException->getErrors();
        $response["code"] = $gException->getCode();
        echo("\n>>>> [START] Google Server Error response:");
        var_dump($response);
        echo("\n>>>> [END] Google Server Error response\n");
    } catch (Exception $e){
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: I believe that this is only available for boarding passes: https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/pass-verticals/use-cases?vertical=boarding-passes#receive-flight-updates

Comment: @Soc I tried it in this way: https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/pass-verticals/use-cases?vertical=loyalty#update-passes or tried to add an extra message (see edit), but still I got no message on the lock screen.

Comment: Messages don't appear in notifications. Instead they appear on the pass itself. Have a look at https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/pass-verticals/pass-template?vertical=event-tickets#default-template. Specifically rows 44 and 45.

Comment: @Soc - you're right. It was just an idea. I actually can't believe that there is no option for Loyalty....

Comment: As of 22 Jan 2023, there are only four ways for a change to a google wallet card to cause a notification to pop up. offertype card expiration, eventtype card upcoming event, flighttype card upcoming flight and flighttype card update. Nothing for loyalty cards right now. Google support team assistant apologised when i asked about notifications for loyalty card updates.